# Resize object in Blender as in Unity

Tags: transforms, unity

Is it possible?
I'm talking about this scaling method from Unity, where you press <kbd>T</kbd> and then you can grab the edge of the object and drag it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you clarified what T does in Unity for Blender users who don't know. What does "grabbing the edge" of the object do after pressing T?

Comment: when you press T in Unity,  4 lines will show up around the selected object (see the second photo i attached in the op) and you can drag by one of those lines to scale the object in a certain direction

Comment: You can press `S` and then`x` `y` or `z` to scale the model along a specific axis. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I know about that, but it's not quite what i want. Pressing S and then scaling on a certain axe witll scale the object on both sides (up and down, left and right).

Comment: @FaraNume you can achieve that by setting a Pivot Point to Active Element and then you scale the object will be scaled towards the last selected face, edge or vertex.